# Can a base DN for LDAP queries be a group DN?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am trying to do LDAP integration for user authentication in HP NNMi. (NNMi on RHEL6 to Active Directory on W2K8 R2)

I know I can get it to work if I use the OU that my users are in as the base DN for the lookup.

Trouble is, my NNMi users exist in many disparate OUs.

So, what I wanted to try was to create a group for NNMi Users, and put them all in that.

Then use the DN for the group as the base DN for the query.

It doesn't work, and I'm not sure if it should. I'm thinking it might be that it only works if the base DN is for an OU.

Can anyone confirm?

*edit*

It's cool, I got it figured out. I leave the base DN to the highest point that all my users are under, then use the filter with memberOf= and that does the trick

Comment: Yep, you've found the way most would do it. It's not uncommon to simply see the Base DN as the root domain level, so literally just `DC=MyDomain,DC=com`

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution I found was setting the base DN to the highest point that all my users are under, then using the filter with memberOf=(DN of my desired group)